# JQuery select between

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery "collection" of li objects (result of applying .filter())...

The collection is named `results` ... Because of javascript pagination i am trying to find an efficient way to make elements visible from index x up to index y... 
This test didnt work

```
results.find(":lt(5):gt(0)").show();
```

Iam just trying to find a non loop method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

think i found it.....
http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: FYI, your original version would have worked using `.filter()` instead of `.find()`, but `.slice()` is nicer.

Answer (score 0):

use [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

```
$(begin).nextUntil(end)
```